# Remove sections of audio in SoX

Tags: wav, sox

What's the easiest way to remove the specified sections of a wav file using SoX? Right now I use the `trim` command to break up the file and then concatenate the parts. However, that seems a little tedious and backwards since `trim` takes a section of audio and copies it to a new file, so I have to trim the opposite of the the sections that I specify to remove, and then concatenate those. Any help appreciated, thanks!